# Authentication for website dedicated to specific client?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a web application / website written in ASP.NET Core. The website is for use by one company and will be accessible over the internet. Because it is for a specific company it therefore has to have authentication for that client only (no public registration).

Is there a service with a C# API that allows me to define what domain is allowed to register and sign in? For example all emails in a specific domain or specific emails in a specific domain e.g. @someCompany.com under google or outlook? I am not yet aware of what email client the customer uses. I am also new to setting up authentication for a web app.

*This may seem like a '`whats the best solution`' kind of question but what I am asking for is a solution to a very technical problem. There will be opinions on best solution but I think the question is valid here. Happy to be convinced otherwise.*

Comment: I get what you’re saying, but I still think the question is off topic because it’s asking “what are all the ways to...” or “what are the best ways to...” that being said, generally speaking you’re looking for a discriminators unique to your customer. That *might* be email domain, but maybe not. Getting a man on the inside to handle account management is probably your best bet. An “admin” if you will. You verify them personally, and they do the rest via an acccount management page.

Comment: @cwharris I agree with you. But really a lot of questions can be viewed that way if you think about it. People will have opinions on what the best approach is. There just isn't a fine line for the definition for off topic sometimes. This really seams like a serious question, though very susceptible to opinions.

Comment: @cwharris regarding your suggestion. I would really prefer to not have to implement an admin page. I will be handling the hosting and will pretty much be the admin. Is there a third party api (paid or not) that would do that job here? You used the term discriminator; is the an official word in this domain? Or you just used that to describe the case? I ask because I'm trying to learn lots in the area. Cheers

Comment: I’m not saying it isn’t a valid question. I’m saying it has no “right answer” and as such does not, as much as many of us would like it to, belong on stack overflow, IMO. It’s a complex question which merits discussion, and therefore does not fit the Q/A format.

Comment: @cwharris good point. Any suggestions on other sites where this would be fitting as a valid question?

Comment: Honestly my answer got me thinking about it, and no, I think that’s why SO gets so many questions like this. Lots of us don’t know of an alternative. I hear Quora is a thing, but I don’t use it.